# Very slow deploy on azure: 'Warning: Unable to connect to the remote server'

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-deployment

I publish an ASP.NET web app as Web Role. 
It has always deployed OK to my MSDN Azure subscription, but now I get a number of 'Warning: Unable to connect to the remote server' messages on each deployment. Sometimes it gives up and sometimes it gets through and finishes the deployment. 
...and it takes a lot of time to finish the process!

I have Win8, Vs2012. One solution that I deploy to different Subscription (one at time).

Any Idea?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, occasionally it publishes first time but most times it takes at least 15 attempts.

Comment: Also having this issue and I believe it started happening after I installed Visual Studio 2012 Update 2.

Answer (score 0):

Run a repair on your Visual Studio 2012 installation by selecting the application name in **Programs and Features** and clicking on *Change*. If that doesn't work, you may also try to re-download your Azure subscription publishing profiles again (remove the current ones from VS first).